# How to setup a website server on local lan on Windows 8 - Apache.PHP.MySQL

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, php, mysql

Trying to setup a website server at home.

Been trying this for weeks, but to no avail. If someone can help I will indeed be grateful, and I will wire over some beers if necessary.

So, I have WINDOWS 8.1 pre-installed on my laptop which I dont want to change. Trawling through the web I have now discovered that Apache, MYSQL SERVER, and PHP are what I need. 
I know how to program fairly okay in SQL and in PHP, so that is no worry. I installed Apaache and PHP however nothing seems to work : when I type http://localhost, I get an "error/timeout" type message in any of my browsers - chrome/IE.
Below are the things I have done so far:

1) SETUP STATIC IP for one of my laptops like so:
    Router: D-Link-600 router
    "LAN Setup" -> DHCP Reservation, pulldown menu, selected one of my laptops, I typed in an IP such as 192.168.0.180 (so it locks down the IP on teh local area network)
    Save settings.

2) SETUP PORT FORWARDING for that laptop on the D-LINK-600 Router:
    Went to "ADVANCED" in the "router-page"
    "Application Name" -> Pull down menu -> "HTTP" then clicked '<<' arrow. 
    Public Port 80 ~ 80 automatically filled in. "Computer Name" -> Chose that same laptop -> IP Address filled in as the one I chose above 192.168.0.180
    Private Port 80 ~ 80 automatically filled in.

3) OPEN FIREWALL ON LAPTOP:
    First uninstalled McAfee coz it was preventing me from changing any settings, I didnt know if it was necessary but I uninstalled it anyway.
    Went to "Control Panel" -> "System and Security" -> "Windows firewall"
    Private Networks: Turn off windows Firewall
    Public Networks: Turn off windows Firewall

4) Allow incoming stuff on PORT 80 on LAPTOP:
    Same place - Windows Firewall and Advanced Settings : Inbound Rule : New rule : PORT : Selected TCP and Specified New Port as 80 : Allow Connection : Domain Private Public : Name"PORT80" : FINISH

Went to website: yougetsignal  to see if port 80 is open - it shows me my "internet" IP (different from locally fixed IP as above) and says PORT 80 is closed (due to "Timeout")

5) APACHE INSTALLATION:
    My "SYSTEM" in control panel is 64 bit operating system.
    Downloaded from Apachelounge.com/download/  httpd-2.4.17-win64-VC14.zip
    Extraced into C:/Apache24

```
httpd.conf have the following lines:
```

httpd.conf additional/altered lines::: start

```
ServerRoot "c:/Apache24"

Listen 192.168.0.180:80

LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2_4.dll"

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php

# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.

#

ServerName Localhost:80      -> was ServerName www.example.com:80, i changed it to Localhost:80

<IfModule dir_module>

        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

</IfModule>

PHPIniDir c:/php
```

httpd.conf additional/altered lines::: end

6) PHP Installation?
    Renamed the "php.ini-development" file to "php.ini"
    Opened it, and enabled some extensions like CURL, MYSQL, etc.
    OUt of curiosity, I ran the file php.exe in c:php folder (all extracted), and it says   MSVCR110.dll file is missing.

7) PUTTING IT ALL TO WORK TOGETHER:

Ran the CMD prompt in Administrator mode. It said some VC***110.dll file is missing - downloaded that, it worked.

however, now the CMD prompt upon installation (c:\Apache24> httpd.exe -k install  ) says: 
"Syntax error on line 178 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load c:/php/php5apache2_4.dll into server: %1 is not a valid win32 application.

went to the APache/bin folder and ran httpd.exe 
went to IE/Chrome and tuped http://Localhost

NOTHING. Just timeout. I Need Help guys.

Is there an older version of APACHE/PHP that I can install and is bound to work?

PLEASE. HELP.

Comment: 1) Configuring your router to always give the same IP address to your webserver-to-be is _not_ "setting up a static IP address". 2) There is no need to configure port forwarding and expose your webserver-to-be to the internet if not even `http://localhost` works. Undo that until you have finished your setup.

Comment: Hi JakeGould, the reason I avoided WAMP it was I wanted to get a more "bricks and mortar" feel to the server/sertup, and whatever learning points on networking in general that might have offered..

Answer (score 2):

I know this can be frustrating, but I would highly recommend uninstalling/removing your apache setup you have so far and install this: http://www.wampserver.com/en/#download-wrapper

I have used this in the past, and it has worked quite well for me.

Comment: yes, remove both your apache install and your PHP install and just use WAMP, it will set it all up for you.  It looks like you're missing some dependencies right now.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen R, and heavyd, How did the Port forwarding/IP Setup etc work for you? I wanna setup this server on one laptop, and use another to check the website (from the same Wifi in my apartment) . For now I don't need it to be accessible from the WWW. Reason I was avoiding WAMP etc until now was that I wanted to learn a bit more about networking/whatever in the process, and needed a more bare-bones feel to the server setup. Thanks for any inputs, guys..

Comment: You shouldn't have to do any port forwarding if you are only going to be accessing the site on your internal/private network.  When you get to the point where you need to access it externally, then you will need to setup port forwarding.

Comment: @Stephen R, thanks a lot for your advise! saved a lot of trouble! thank you

Comment: @Madventures, sure no problem!